# Random String generation - avoiding duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, random

I am using the below code to generate random keys like the following **TX8L1I**

```
public string GetNewId()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            short codeLength = 5;
            string chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(codeLength);

            for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; ++i)
                builder.Append(chars[rnd.Next(chars.Length)]);

            result = string.Format("{0}{1}", "T", builder.ToString()); 

            return result;
        }
```

Every-time a key is generated a correspondent record is created on the database using the generated result as primary key. Off course this is not safe since a primary key violation might occur.

What's the correct approach to this? Should I load all existing keys and verify against tha t list if the key already exist and if yes generate another one?

Or maybe a more efficient way would be to move this logic into the database side? But even on the database side I still need to check that the random key generated does not exist on the current table.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: ...what about a primary key of type `uniqueidentifier`... ?

Comment: Is there any requirement on having a key with length of 6 and starting with T?

Comment: There are 60466176 possible codes. Generate them all in the database and mark each one that's been used (by a column or by deleting used rows). Then you just need to make sure that "select a code, mark it as used, return the value" is serialized or avoids collisions - easily done in most databases.

Comment: I'd avoid the entire issue entirely by not using random keys, but to answer as to just how I'd not use random keys I'd need to understand the problem you're trying to solve by using them.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Yes I need to generate strings with the format that I provided (e.g TX8L1I)

Comment: @JonHanna well my decision to use the random is that I don't want the users to be able to know how the keys are generated (format), since the website is public and I don't want users to be trying to access keys that.

Comment: Then I would prabably use same kind of solution as @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested. ie create pool where you can take keys from and then mark them as used.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought I would have more possibilities sincerely. Maybe I need to add an additional character or something.

Comment: Just go for Guid if you can change the id and it needs to be displayed to users and they can somehow manipulate with what key they are accessing

Comment: You've got 36 possible characters and you're selecting from that set 5 times - which means 36^5 total combinations.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I really believe that your approach is the most  correct way to do it. I will probably open a new question on how the best way to create all those codes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever adding an additional character to the set (6 times) would create a huge number of records which probably makes it "impossible" to follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the decision to the database. Add a primary key of type `uniqueidentifier`. Then its a simple "fire and forget" algorithm.. the database decides what the key is.

Comment: I cannot use your approach since I need a small key, not a Guid.

Comment: Well, I think I will use it. It's not a small code, but who cares.. Copy-Paste it's the rule nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `Random` instance outside of your method.

Since `Random` object is [*seeded from the system clock*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx), which means that if you call your method several times very quickly, it will use the same seed each time, which means that you'll get the same string at the end.

Answer (score 2):

> well my decision to use the random is that I don't want the users to be able to know how the keys are generated (format), since the website is public and I don't want users to be trying to access keys that.

You've merged two problems into one that are really separate:

1. Identify a row in a database.
2. Have an identifier that is passed to and from clients, that matches this, but is not predictable.

This is a specific case of a more general set of two problems:

1. Identify a row in a database.
2. Have an identifier that is passed to and from clients, that matches this.

In this case, when we don't care about guessing, then the easiest way to deal with it is to just use the same identifier. E.g. for the database row identified by the integer `42` we use the string `"42"` and the mapping is a trivial `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` in one direction and a trivial `.ToString()` or implicit `.ToString()` in the other.

And that's therefore the pattern we use without even thinking about it; public IDs and database keys are the same (perhaps with some conversion).

But the best solution to your specific case where you want to prevent guessing is **not** to change the key, but to change mapping between the key and the public identifier.

First, use auto-incremented integers ("IDENTITY" in SQL Server, and various similar concepts in other databases).

Then, when you are sending the key to the client (i.e. using it in a form value or appending it to a URI) then map it as so:

```
private const string Seed = "this is my secret seed ¾Ÿˇʣכ ↼⊜┲◗ blah balh";
private static string GetProtectedID(int id)
{
  using(var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create())
  {
    return string.Join("", sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id.ToString() + Seed)).Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))) + id.ToString();
  }
}
```

For example, with an ID of `123` this produces `"989178D90470D8777F77C972AF46C4DED41EF0D9123"`.

Now map back to a the key with:

```
private static bool GetIDFromProtectedID(string str, out int id)
{
  int chkID;
  if(int.TryParse(str.Substring(40), out chkID))
  {
    using(var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create())
    {
      if(string.Join("", sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chkID.ToString() + Seed)).Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))) == str.Substring(0, 40))
      {
        id = chkID;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  id = 0;
  return false;
}
```

For `"989178D90470D8777F77C972AF46C4DED41EF0D9123"` this returns `true` and sets the `id` argument to `123`. For `"989178D90470D8777F77C972AF46C4DED41EF0D9122"` (because I tried to guess the ID to attack your site) it returns `false` and sets `id` to `0`. (The correct ID for key `122` is `"F8AD0F55CA1B9426D18F684C4857E0C4D43984BA122"`, which is not easy to guess from having seen that for `123`).

If you want, you can remove some of the 40 characters of the output to produce smaller IDs. This makes it less secure (an attacker has fewer possible IDs to brute-force) but should still be reasonable for many uses.

Obviously, you should used a different value for `Seed` than here, so that someone reading this answer can't use it to predict your ID; change the seed, change the ID. `Seed` cannot be changed once set without altering every ID in the system. Sometimes that's a good thing (if identifiers are never meant to have long-term value anyway), but normally it's bad (you've just 404d every page in the site that used it).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am really confused. I understand your approach to have an internal procedure to match public ID's with database ID's however the general public ID's must be short (e.g 6 characters) and everyone will know more or less how these ID's look like (e.g T45RED) so even with that logic I can only have one T45RED, so the long database ID you suggested will be only one for this code. So the users might try to guess different codes (e.g T45DDX). I am not really understanding the advantaged of what you are suggesting me, sorry maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Ah. I did not see the requirement for short public identifiers. Are they going to be manually entered or something? The advantage of my answer is that the DB code is simple (it just uses 1, 2, 3, 4...) but the ID is really hard to guess. With you requirement I'd probably pre-calculate a set of say 10,000 codes and use them in turn until I was down to around 2,000.

Comment: @SonerGönül it does fail to hit their requirement for a short ID size, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the logic to the database instead. Even though the database still have to check for the existence of the key, it's already within the database operation at that point, so there is no back-and-forth happening.

Also, if there's an index on this randomly generated key, a simple if exists will be quick enough to determine if the key has been used before or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

Generate your string as well as concatenate the following onto it

```
string newUniqueString = string.Format("{0}{1}", result, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff"));
```

This way, you will never have the same key ever again!

Or use

```
var StringGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre but I need to generate strings with the format that I provided **(e.g TX8L1I)**

Comment: Play around with `new Guid()`, you can add parameters to format it aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You've commited a *typical sin* with `Random`: one shouldn't create `Random` instance
each time they want to generate random value (otherwise one'll get *badly skewed* distribution with *many repeats*). Put `Random` away form function:

```
// Let Generator be thread safe
private static ThreadLocal<Random> s_Generator = new ThreadLocal<Random>(
 () => new Random());

public static Random Generator {
  get {
    return s_Generator.Value;
  }
}

// For repetition test. One can remove repetion test if 
// number of generated ids << 15000
private HashSet<String> m_UsedIds = new HashSet<String>();

public string GetNewId() {
  int codeLength = 5;
  string chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  while (true) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(codeLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; ++i)
      builder.Append(chars[Generator.Next(chars.Length)]); // <- same generator for all calls

    result = string.Format("{0}{1}", "T", builder.ToString()); 

    // Test if random string in fact a repetition
    if (m_UsedIds.Contains(result))
      continue;

    m_UsedIds.Add(result);

    return result;
  }
}
```

For `codeLength = 5` there're `Math.Pow(chars.Length, codeLength)` *possible
strings* `(Math.Pow(36, 5) == 60466176 = 6e7)`. According to *birthday paradox*
you can expect 1st repetition at about `2 * sqrt(possible strings) == 2 * sqrt(6e7) == 15000`. If it's OK, you can skip the repetition test, otherwise `HashSet<String>` could 
be a solution.